# Accessing own Dropbox storage from an application

Tags: dropbox, dropbox-api, dropbox-sdk

I would very much like to enable users of my app to backup some of app data on their own Dropbox. I would like to direct users to login to their Dropbox account with their email and password and then the app would generate and store a file there without users having do anything on their own.

Is this possible?

I wouldn't want users to have to go to Dropbox App Console and then Create App and then fill in all the options and then copy the access token and paste in my app manually. That would repel a lot them.

I haven't seen anything in the docs suggesting that programmatic access to an account without an app created in the Console and generated access token is possible? Did I miss something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is possible. You as the developer would [register](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/apps/create) the app once, and implement the Dropbox OAuth app authorization flow in your app to allow your end-users to then connect your app to their accounts.

You may want to check out the following guides:

- https://www.dropbox.com/developers/reference/getting-started
- https://developers.dropbox.com/oauth-guide
- https://developers.dropbox.com/dbx-file-access-guide

Comment: thanks @Greg, oauth flow did the thing